# HttpClient: What is the difference between ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy and HttpRequestRetryHandler?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I was hoping to deal with this situation where i want it to do retry after a delay, but it seems that the delay that i set in ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy didnt take place :

> 19:42:29.046 [scheduler-15] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec -
>   I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException ) caught when
>   processing request to {}->http://testing.com:80: The target server
>   failed to respond 19:42:29.049 [scheduler-15] INFO 
>   o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Retrying request to
>   {}->http://testing.com:80

I have both of [ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy.html) and [HttpRequestRetryHandler](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpRequestRetryHandler.html) set. And from both, it seems that only ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy has a delay option, where i dont see any delay options for httpRequestRetryHandler.

So in the case of the NoHttpResponseException above, which one is actually used ? And what's the difference between those two ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- HttpRequestRetryHandler represents a strategy determining whether or not the request is safe to retry in case of an I/O error (no HTTP response has been received from the server).
- ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy represents a strategy determining whether or not the request should be retried after a while in case of the service being temporarily unavailable (response status 503).

In 5.0 the two interfaces are likely to get replaced by a single strategy interface.

Comment: Definition regarding `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy` is wrong.
The DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy is the one that does what is written above.

The ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy is just an interface where you can also implement totally your own logic.