# How to implement HttpRequestRetryHandler and ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy in apache httpclient5

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am updating the project to use httpclient5, I would like to know what is the relevant class to use for `HttpRequestRetryHandler` and `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy`

The code snippet we have is as below

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpRequestRetryHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy;
```

```
.setRetryHandler(new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {
  @Override
  public boolean retryRequest(IOException exp, int count, HttpContext context) {
    // code block
  }
)
.setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(new ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy() {
  @Override
  public boolean retryRequest(HttpResponse res, int count, HttpContext context) {
    // code block
  }
)
```

Could someone help and explain what is the new class in httpclient5 and how this code block can be rewritten?

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpRequestRetryHandler` and `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy` got [merged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24230642/2049986) into the [HttpRequestRetryStrategy](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/HttpRequestRetryStrategy.html).

So your new implementation would be:

```
.setRetryStrategy(new HttpRequestRetryStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(HttpRequest request, IOException exception, int execCount, HttpContext context) {
        // code block
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retryRequest(HttpResponse response, int execCount, HttpContext context) {
        // code block
    }

    @Override
    public TimeValue getRetryInterval(HttpResponse response, int execCount, HttpContext context) {
        // code block
    }
});
```